# How to make a ListBox control scroll automatically and smoothly in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, listbox, autoscroll

Some say I can use ScrollIntoView method to deal with this issue, but ScrollIntoView can only scroll the ListBox logically, not physically.Is there any way to make a ListBox scroll automatically, and seems like someone is dragging its scroll-bar smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ScrollViewer instead of ListBox. ScrollViewer has ScrollToVerticalOffset(Double offset) and ScrollToHorizontalOffset(Double offset) methods which you can use to scroll it automatically.